# ¿Como pasar dos data table serializadas en un webMethod?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net

Hola espero me puedan ayudar con esto. Tengo un procedimiento almacenado que devuelve dos select. En mi webMethod necesito enviar las dos tablas que tengo en mi dataset para trabajar con jquery y ajax. ¿Algiuen sabe como hacer esto para enviar las dos tablas de mi dataset y recibirlas a traves de ajax y jquery? Gracias.

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static string Intervalo(int id_Persona, string Sucursal, int rol) 
{
    Transacciones t = new Transacciones();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable tabla_Personas = new DataTable();
    DataTable tabla_imagenPasos = new DataTable();
    ds = t.Mostrar_Personas(id_Persona, Sucursal, rol);
    tabla_Persona = ds.Tables[0];            
    tabla_imagenPasos = ds.Tables[1];
    DataRow row = tabla_imagenPasos.Rows[0];
    string datos = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tabla_Personas, Formatting.Indented);//aqui solo envio una tabla pero quiero enviar las dos. para trabajar con ajax y jquery

    return datos;        

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sobre tú lógica tocará concatenar la segunda tabla.

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static string Intervalo(int id_Persona, string Sucursal, int rol) 
{
    //...logica del metodo
    string datos = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tabla_Personas, Formatting.Indented);//aqui solo envio una tabla pero quiero enviar las dos. para trabajar con ajax y jquery
    datos += JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tabla_dos, Formatting.Indented);
    return datos;        

}
```

Comment: Hola @Aaron Romero gracias me a servido tu respuesta. Ahora como trabajar con tablas separadas en lado del cliente con Jquery y ajax.

Comment: ¿De que forma tienes configurado tu ajax?  edita tu pregunta e incluyelo.

Comment: Hola @Aaron Romero he creado una nueva  pregunta donde incluyo mi codigo puedes verla aqui. [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/245053/como-trabajar-con-tablas-separadas-en-ajax-con-jquery-despues-de-enviar-dos-tab]